# count number of seconds longpress

Tags: javascript

I'm working in this long press time counter

**PROBLEM**
It works well, but now instead of displaying time differences (end - start), I want it to display count numbers like working with `count++` (1,2,3,4....)

I tried using `delta = end.getSeconds()  - start.getSeconds() ;` or `delta = end.getMilliseconds() - start.getMilliseconds();`but sometimes it shows negative numbers https://jsfiddle.net/7h65ufLq/18/

```js
(function(window, document, undefined){
 'use strict';
 var start;
 var end;
 var delta;
 var button =  document.getElementById('myCanvas');
function getDate(){
   start = new Date();
 }
 
 function retrieveDate() {
   end = new Date();
   delta = end - start;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = delta;
 }
 
 button.addEventListener("mousedown", getDate);
 button.addEventListener("mouseup",retrieveDate );
 
  button.addEventListener("touchstart", getDate);
 button.addEventListener("touchend",retrieveDate );
 document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault())
})(window, document)
```

```css
#myCanvas{
  
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
-webkit-user-select: auto;
  -webkit-touch-callout: inherit;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">click</canvas>
<span id="demo">0</span>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'I want it to display count numbers like working with count++'

Comment: ok, display integers. like 1,2,3,4,5,6....showing the time the canvas was pressed. my english is not the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than display a delta time, you could just start an interval that increases the count at specific times. Then on mouse up, clear the interval.

For example:

```js
(function(window, document, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  var button = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var interval;
  var count;

  function startCount() {
    count = 0
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      count++;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count
    }, 1000) // increase count every second
  }

  function endCount() {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }

  button.addEventListener("mousedown", startCount);
  button.addEventListener("mouseup", endCount);

  button.addEventListener("touchstart", startCount);
  button.addEventListener("touchend", endCount);
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault())
})(window, document)
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  -webkit-touch-callout: inherit;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">click</canvas>
<span id="demo">0</span>
```

Comment: ok, thank you for your approach. In this case count doesnt return to 0 once the mouse is up?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, see edit - you can simply reset the counter in the mouse down handler.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7h65ufLq/27/ Im testing it here, the count doesnt return to 0, with that, the code would work terrific, thanks

Comment: @Dan you can just set the `innerHTML` to 0 at the beginning of `startCount` -- see another edit.